# creating new excel application taking 40 seconds

Tags: c#, .net, excel

My code takes 40 seconds on this statement: Application xlsApp = new Application();
Any idea why that would be? I am running this locally.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

namespace Mynamespace.Controllers
{
    public class ExcelParser
    {
        public static string[] ReadIdColumn(string filename)
        {

            Application xlsApp = new Application();// have breakpoint here and takes 40                seconds from this line to the next.
            Workbook wb = xlsApp.Workbooks.Open(filename,
            0, true, 5, "", "", true, XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true);
             //parsing and other logic here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a lot of Excel addins installed? I have found that many organizations use a lot of addins, often loading from some network location. I have seen cases where Excel takes up to 5 minutes to load.

Comment: How long does excel take if you just load it from clicking the icon on your start menu?

Comment: Wow guys that was fast. This is why stackoverflow is so awesome. Yes I have add-ins and yes my excel takes long time to open. I did not realize it was using my local instance of excel driver.

Comment: After uninstalling the add-ons it is taking 15 seconds rather than 40 seconds. Much better. Is it generally that slow? I have reference to Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel dll. So I am not sure which it is using local instance of my excell installation. Should not it be self contained if I have installed it through nuget in my reference?

Comment: The interop library isn't Excel itself.  It simply provides a way for your application to interact with Excel.

Comment: Normally it should take about 1-2 seconds to load Excel application. If you have add-ins -> disable all. If the file itself is a huge on compare the Interop vs. normall double click on the icon opening time.